# Error of changeable value, Laravel, Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with referencing the object type variable in the view.

```
 $x = (object) [
         'number' => (object) [
             'original' => $key,
             'x' => $c,
           ]
     ];
```

In the controller, I can easily refer to it,

```
dd($x->number->x);
```

but if I send it to the non-random view, I get an error.

```
        @foreach($x->number as $number)

            {{ $number->x }}

        @endforeach
```

> Trying to get property of non-object

When I tried the same with the array, it was the same error or

> Illegal string offset 'x'

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can't you just `{{ dd($x->number->x) }}` in your blade too? Why `foreach()`?

Comment: because there are more number objects

Comment: Your `$x->number` is an object. You cannot loop over that using foreach. You need to have an array of objects here, i.e. `$x = (object) ['number' => [(object) ['original' => $key, 'x' => $c]]];` @DominikMrozek

Answer (score 1):

Your `$x` variable should actually look like

```
$x = (object) [
     'number' => [
         (object) [
              'original' => $key,
              'x' => $c,
         ]
     ]
 ];
```

In order to be able to loop over the `$x->number` variable

Comment: I've already fixed the mistake. Since I want to store a lot of number objects in a variable, they must have different values

Comment: $x = (object) [
                            $key => (object) [
                                'qt' => $value,
                                'x' => $c,
                            ]
                        ];

Answer (score 0):

With your `foreach` you define `$number` in your blade as `number`. So you cant access `x & original` via property accessor. Because it tries to iterate through the properties.

Try

```
@foreach($x as $number)

    {{ $number->x }}

@endforeach
```